# Checking startup time, reloadtime and compile time

Tags: javascript, performance, polymer, polymer-2.x

So I have a Polymer 2.0 application and I want to compare it to an Android application but how can I check startup time? Reload time during development is instantly I guess because when you are running the local server it gets update automaticly after you saved? And compile time doesn't happen right? As far as I know Javascript doesn't get compiled?

Comment: Have you tried to use chrome devtools? It has a mode where it can inspect web pages on your phone, so you can use it to time the page load time.

Comment: All code is compiled, at least once. JavaScript is simply compiled when it is loaded. As far as how to check "startup time"; you'll need to be more specific. There are many, many events in [the Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API) which could conceivably considered "startup complete".

Comment: Oh, I might try that. I thought Polymer would've had something to analyze in the Polymer CLI